# “surely” vs. “really"

Tags: adverbs

> This **really** looks bad.

vs.

> This **surely** looks bad.

What is the difference between the adverbs *surely* and *really*?

Don’t they both lay emphasis on certainity?

Also:

> You **surely** do know how to make me happy.

vs.

> You **really** do know how to make me happy.

Here, why does the use of word *surely* sound a bit unnatural?

Answer (score 1):

**Surely** puts emphasis on the level of certainty, whereas **really** usually puts emphasis on scale. For clarity, you could say "That looks really bad" and achieve the same meaning as "That really looks bad." You could use **surely** interchangeably in the latter instance, but not the former; "That looks surely bad" doesn't make sense.

Incidentally, the word **surely** isn't often used in English in this context, and **really** is much more common. I mostly hear the word **surely** in posing a negative statement or question, like this:

> Surely you don't intend to stay up all night finishing that paper?

That sentence is saying, "You don't intend to stay up all night finishing that paper, do you?" Here's another example:

> Surely he'll be back soon.

Even though the word "surely" means a high or absolute certainty, in this sense it's used to express uncertainty.